# Calling task_tick_fair in CFS algorithm

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, cfs

Why is there a `for_each_sched_entity` macro in `task_tick_fair` function called on system tick? According to me, only the run time characteristics of the current task should be updated. Why does it call `entity_tick` for the entire hierarchy of the current process?

Answer (score 0):

CFS supports hierarchies of tasks, where entire subtrees can have their CPU usage accounting and quota aggregated. This features is used to implement [cpu cgroups](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.rst?id=4fa640dc52302b5e62b01b05c755b055549633ae#n957) and [CFS group scheduling](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.rst?id=4fa640dc52302b5e62b01b05c755b055549633ae#n205). A interior node of the task tree can be thought of a as a virtual task than represents the CPU usage of its subtree.